# VBA Access text to speach other language

Tags: vba, ms-access, text-to-speech

In VBA, I have a buttom, when I click on it, it should give me de spoken text in Dutch of the textbox.

[image]

In windows/control panel/speech recognition/text to speach I have two languages (Bart-Dutch / Zira-English), however in VBA I have the following code (for testing), and I only get one language, Zira, the English one. How can I make Bart talking?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim voc As SpeechLib.SpVoice
Set voc = New SpVoice
Debug.Print voc.GetVoices.Count & " available voices:"
For i = 0 To voc.GetVoices.Count - 1
    Set voc.Voice = voc.GetVoices.Item(i)
    Debug.Print " " & i & " - " & voc.Voice.GetDescription
    voc.Speak "test audio"
Next i
```

1 available voices:
0 - Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`SelectVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice?view=netframework-4.8) method? You may also try using the [`SpeakSSML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakssml?view=netframework-4.8) to force the language - note the `xml:lang` attribute *(I don't speak VB, so syntax is probably wrong):

```
voc.SpeakSSML '<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="nl">test audio</speak>'
```

Also, note that Windows 10 has two different subsystems for speech, so you may get a different set of listings depending on libraries used. For reference, here's two different Powershell examples of using [System.Speech.Synthesis](https://gist.github.com/lselden/cde51ca2debdd7c7c16ea4abf621f8d5) and [Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis](https://gist.github.com/lselden/ab2e04fbac785e0644c4b562bf5e35cd)